# how can add extra key,value to response of request in python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I need to add some extra key, value to response in `requests` lib of python3 without changing response structure (because the response will be sent into another service for the process). for example, I received this response:

```
>>import requests
>>r = requests.post(url=input_kong_address, data=data)
>>print(r.json())
{
    "foo":"bar",
    "key1":"val1"
}
```

I need to add `"extra_key":"extra_value"` to response:

```
{
    "foo":"bar",
    "key1":"val1",
    "extra_key":"extra_value"
}
```

and now I want to add some extra key to response and sent it to the next service without changing in structure (class, type and etc):

```
>>import requests
>>import json
>>r = requests.post(url=input_kong_address, data=data)
>>response_data = r.json()
>>response_data['extra_key']='extra_value'  # trying to add extra key and value to response
>>r.json = json.loads(json.dumps(response_data))  #  trying to attach new dict to response
>>r.json() # check is worked?
{TypeError}'dict' object is not callable
```

thank you.

Comment: Please do some experiments before posting a question.

Comment: `json.dumps` and `json.loads` are two opposite actions and applying it on dictionary the way you did, nullifies the effect. 
So json.loads(json.dumps(response_data)) returns response_data only.

Comment: `response_data` is of type `dictionary`. Hence r.json is of type dictionary (though it is very unclever to perform such assignment)
Python dictionary does not implement `__call__` method. Hence it is not `callable` , as the error suggests.

Comment: Finally, if you want to modify response you received then you modify and pass `response_data`  to the next service. Nothing more needs to be done.
Like : `r2 = requests.get('next_service_url', data=response_data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.json()` is a method, so rebinding it to a dict can only lead to this behaviour indeed. Now if you [read the source of the response class](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L587), you'll find out that this method actually operates on the `._content` attribute (accessed via either the `.content` and/or `.text` properties). IOW, you just have to assign your serialized json string to `response._content`:

```
>>> import requests
>>> import json
>>> r = requests.get("https://www.google.com")
>>> r._content = json.dumps({"foo": "bar"})
>>> r.json()
{u'foo': u'bar'}
>>>
```

This being said:

> the response will be sent into another service for the process

you may want to think twice about your design then. It's of course impossible to tell without knowing much more about your concrete use case, but ask yourself whether this "other service" really needs the whole response object.

Comment: Thank you. worked! I know it's not the best way to add key/value in this way but the problem is I'm working on a project that is a part of the old bigger project. so I can't change the logic of other services and the service that I contact with it need a response project. we will refacto it after some feature finish :). again thank you master